# Kurento : Rewinding a live video stream

Tags: gstreamer, kurento

I was wondering if we can rewind a live video stream or maybe use recorder endpoint to show a different video element on the screen and then rewind the video using recorder endpoint. Is it possible to achieve this by RecorderEndpoint or can it be achieved by writing some custom kurento module using some gstreamer plugins?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I have no knowledge about this one - just curious.. what exactly is this RecorderEndpoint - its some module of kurento? The kurento is using GStreamer? You mean that client requests rewind/seek, and your server would seek the streamed file? It sounds like its possible

Comment: RecorderEndpoint is a kurento plugin which helps to record live video streams into a file. yes kurento is using gstreamer. yes client will request to rewind/seek and mediaserver will seek the stream

Comment: then I do not understand why would you do that with RecoredrEndpoint (I have no idea how is that working - the kurento [docs](http://readthedocs.org/projects/doc-kurento/downloads/pdf/stable/) are unavailable now).. the idea is tell the server to seek the served content and the server will do the seek internally.. so maybe just implement some api (maybe somewhere in [webrtcendpoint](https://github.com/Kurento/kms-elements/tree/master/src/gst-plugins/webrtcendpoint), maybe in session - I dont know?) which will do the seeking and will start serving different part of the file..